# Losing concentration in the middle of the first blessing of Shemoneh Esrei

Tags: halacha, tefilla, blessing, halacha-theory, rambam

***First, a little background information***:

According to *halakhah,* there are two types of *berakhoth*: "long" and "short."

***"Long"*** *berakhoth" are those that have a *pethihah* ("opening", i.e. "*Barukh Atah HaShem Elohenu Melekh Ha-Olam...*", a somewhat extended "middle" section, and then end with a *hathimah* ("ending", i.e. "...*Barukh Atah HaShem _____________*"). Another type of "long" *berakhah* is called *samukhah le-haverta* ("relying on its neighbor") and does not itself have a *pethihah*, but "relies" as it were on the opening of the *berakhah* that was said directly before it.

***"Short"*** *berakhoth* consist of a *pethihah* only, like the *berakhoth* recited before eating, drinking, *misswoth*, etc.

[The Rambam discusses these issues in the following sections: *Hilkhoth Qiryath Shema* 1:8; *Hilkhoth Berakhoth* 1:15.]

In the *halakhoth* regarding the *shemoneh esrei*, it states that one must have *kawwanah* during the first *berakhah* of the prayer or he must return to the beginning. However, if one has proper *kawwanah* during the first blessing and then subsequently loses his *kawwanah* at any other time in the prayer, he does not have to return to the beginning and is still *yosse yedhei hovatho*. [See Rambam, *Hilkhoth Tefillah* 10:1]

The Rambam also mentions that if someone mistakenly says the incorrect *berakhoth* for *Qiryath Shema* (i.e. night ones during the day or vice-versa), they fulfill their obligation as long as the *hathimah* is the correct *hathimah*. This is true because of the principle that says, "*She-kol ha-berakhoth holkhoth aharei hathimathan* - For all blessings are determined by their *hathimah*" (See *Hilkhoth Qiryath Shema* 1:9[8]).

***Now for my question***:

If someone is beginning to pray the *shemoneh esrei* and says the *pethihah* of the first *berakhah* with proper *kawannah* and then, during the middle section has stray thoughts or loses *kawwanah*, but then regains his clear mind and *kawwanah* during the *hathimah* - does he need to begin again? Or does his concentration during the *hathimah* suffice since that is how all *berakhoth* are reckoned?

[**NOTE**: I recognize that there are *shittoth* (usually associated with the commentators on the *Tur* and *Shulhan Arukh*)  that hold that no one is capable of proper *kawwanah* in our times, and so this question is essentially moot. However, I am assuming here that what the *gemara* and the Rambam say on this matter still applies. Thanks.]

Comment: Your question is still a little confusing - did they say all the words with kavanah or not? did they start normally, drift, and then catch themselves just in time to say the chatimah, but didn't go back to reread words they had said absent-mindedly?

Comment: Your question is still interesting as a theoretical accd to those opinions. I don't know why you have to assume either way in that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Shulchan Aruch Harav ([OC 185:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=548&hilite=), [English](http://www.chabad.org/3335603/)) discusses having *kavana* when saying *brochos*, and equates the first *brocha* of *shemoneh esrei* with any other *brocha* that has a *pesichah* and a *chasimah*.

Accordingly:

- One must have *kavana* when saying the *pesichah* and *chasimah* of the first *berachah*. If he did not have *kavanah* by any one of them, he must repeat the *Shemoneh Esrei*.
- One should *l'chatchila* have *kavanah* when saying the middle part of the *berachah*. If, however, he did not, it is not necessary to repeat the *Shemoneh Esrei*.

Comment: The OP was specifically asking according to the opinion of Rambam [(Hilkhot Tefillah 10:1)](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2210.htm#1). The view you reference does not seem to be in accordance with this, and accordingly, is not an answer.

Comment: @mevaqesh He's asking according to the Rambam's view (as opposed to the Tur's view) that if one did not have proper *kavana* while saying the first *beracha*, he must repeat the *shemoneh esreh*. In any case, the Rambam doesn't discuss what qualifies as having *kavanah*; my answer brings a source which discusses what qualifies as having *kavanah*.

Comment: "namely that one must have kavana - even b'dieved" What does it mean that kavanah is required even b'diavad, if "He does not need to repeat the shemoneh esrei"?

Comment: @mevaqesh "He does not need to repeat the shemoneh esrei" was directly answering the OP's question. The question was in a case where one had *kavanah* when saying the *pesichah*, but then his mind wandered off in the middle of the *berachah*. The finishing part of the sentence "namely that one must have kavana - even b'dieved" is "only when saying the *pesichah* and *chasimah*".

Comment: Do you mean that if he had kavanah in neither the petiha or the hatima that he _would_ need to repeat the Amidah? Something else? Regardless consider clarifying things in the post itself, not the comments.