# What happens if I forget to say the Pasuk before Shemonah Esrei - "ה" שפתי תפתח ופי יגיד תהלתיך"?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book

Every Tefilah, before Shemonah Esrei, we say a Pasuk from Tehillim - "ה" שפתי תפתח ופי יגיד תהלתיך"

What should I do if I leave out the Pasuk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Beiur Halacha ([111:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%91)) suspects that it would not invalidate the prayer. Accordingly, you'd just keep on going.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97866/759